# Custom Attribute Filter throwing System.NullReferenceException

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am implementing a dynamic File Download from a WebAPI using this http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/

The key here is it sets a cookie with the request in a custom Attribute Filter which tells the browser when the file has finished generating, the loading message is then removed and the file streamed to the browser.

This all works fine when I test locally but when it is deployed to a server I get a System.NullReferenceException. The error points to the attribute filter - the link above has an example of how to do this in ASP.NET MVC 3 but I am using 4 so converted to this -

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class FileDownloadAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string CookieName { get; set; }

    public string CookiePath { get; set; }

    public FileDownloadAttribute(string cookieName = "fileDownload", string cookiePath = "/")
    {
        CookieName = cookieName;
        CookiePath = cookiePath;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        CheckAndHandleFileResult(actionExecutedContext);

        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Write a cookie to inform jquery.fileDownload that a successful file download has occured
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filterContext"></param>
    private void CheckAndHandleFileResult(HttpActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        List<CookieHeaderValue> cookies = new List<CookieHeaderValue>();
        CookieHeaderValue cookie = new CookieHeaderValue(CookieName, "true"){ Path = CookiePath };
        cookies.Add(cookie);

        filterContext.Response.Headers.AddCookies(cookies);
    }
}
```

This is the error I get

System.NullReferenceException at API.Attributes.FileDownloadAttribute.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext) in c:\Dev\Pensions\Main\API\Attributes\FileDownloadAttribute.cs:line 28 at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.CallOnActionExecuted(HttpActionContext actionContext, HttpResponseMessage response, Exception exception) at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<>c_*DisplayClass2.b*_1(CatchInfo`1 info) at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4`1.b__3() at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.CatchImpl[TResult](Task task, Func`1 continuation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Anyone have any ideas? I don't understand why it is fine running locally (through IIS) but not when deployed to a server.

EDIT -

Line 28 in the error refers to this one

```
CheckAndHandleFileResult(actionExecutedContext);
```

EDIT 2- Updated with full Attribute Filter class

Comment: Which line is line 28 of FileDownloadAttribute.cs?

Comment: Where are `CookieName` and `CookiePath` initialized?

Comment: Have you actually tried debugging the code and checking what's null? Can't be too difficult for a 4-line method.